# Нету поле для редактирования URL страницы

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на wordpress, шаблон twentytwenty.
Нету поле для редактирования URL [image: Скрин из админки]
Данный шаблон не первый раз использую, в других сайтах можно редактировать url.
C чем это связано и как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Админка -- Настройки -- Постоянные ссылки, выбрать "Название записи", сохранить.

И будет вам счастье.

Comment: Вопрос не об этом

Comment: @SeVlad, возможность редактирования урлов появляется после включения данных настроек

Comment: А, ну это да. (только на скрине увидел что оказывается ЧПУ не включены. Не думал что ТС настолько... далёк от элементарных вещей.)